# Bitrise error: cocoapods project-workspace mapping error

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, bitrise

Using Bitrise for the first time, I tried to create the validation in their web wizard. First, the "share" tag was needed inside my Xcode scheme - but then the following error occurs during Bitrise validation:

> Failed to determine cocoapods project-workspace mapping, error: project not found at: MyProject.xcodeproj

How can I correct this ?

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple projects in your workspace? If so, you need to specify them at the top of your podfile.

For example:

```
workspace 'YourWorkspace'
project 'project1folder/project1.xcodeproj'
project 'project2folder/project2.xcodeproj'

target 'project1' do

...
```

Comment: this fixed our issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this:

(0. it is always necessary to push your newest .git to the remote repo in order for bitrise to recognize the newest changes)...this alone did not help tough...

Here are the steps that did help:

1. delete all your pods-folders, podfile.lock-file and also your myproject.xcworkspace file
2. pod install again..
3. re-open your newly created xcworkspace file
4. inside Xcode, go to "Edit Schemes"--> Manage-Schemes (right click run-button to find it)
5. delete all your existing Schemes (all of them, also the pods ones...)
6. inside Scheme-manager - press the Plus button
7. add your project
8. (if there add your WatchKit or other extension Schemes)
9. for all newly added Schemes, press the "share" tag
10. commit these changes in git and push to your repo

--> after these 10 steps, the previous error in bitrise does not show up anymore...

Comment: This definitely shouldn't be required The error itself means that your Xcode project, the one in your repo, includes a reference to a file that's not stored in your repository / can not be found in the repository. If you have some time please contact our support via email or the onsite chat on bitrise.io so that they can check the related files, the support guys are always happy to help :)